# How to repair a drive after accidentally changing the partition scheme?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, startup, partition

I was using the Boot Camp. Somehow I managed to change the GPT partition scheme on my external hard drive to a MBR partition scheme. Below is the output from the command `sudo gpt -r -vvv show /dev/disk1`.

```
gpt show: /dev/disk1: mediasize=1000204886016; sectorsize=512; blocks=1953525168
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Bad CRC in GPT table at sector 2
gpt show: /dev/disk1: Sec GPT at sector 1953525167
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         MBR
           1      409639         
      409640  1829583888      2  MBR part 175
  1829993528     1531680      3  MBR part 171
  1831525208   121999927         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

I was booting OS X from this external drive. I am trying to make this drive functional without losing all the data on it.

Comment: I can see that you changed the partitioning scheme from GPT to MBR. The problem seems to be repairable. Normally, Macs boot from `disk0`. Why do you show `disk1`?

Comment: It is showing disk1 because it is setup through a external usb I reinstalled OSX on another hard drive

Comment: I am attempting to get this question reopened. If my edits are wrong, then make corrections. If the question does not get reopened, then I will try to find another way to post an answer.

Comment: The question is clear to me and describes a common situation. How can I submit an answer to it?

Answer (score 1):

The output from the `gpt` command indicates the following.

- While there is no indication that there is a problem with the primary
  GUID Partition Table (GPT) header, the entries appear to have been
  corrupted.
- The secondary (backup) GPT header and entries are intact.
- The MBR tables contains at least two partition entries. One entry is
  a OS X partition (type 175=0xAF). Another entry is an OS X recovery
  partition (type 171=0xAB).

Under normal circumstances, the following is true.

- The `gpt` command does not display MBR partition entry for partitions
  of type 0xEE.
- Some of the primary and secondary GPT headers values differ,
  therefore the headers not identical.
- The primary and secondary GPT entries themselves are actually
  identical.

Therefore, copying the entries, from the secondary GPT to the primary GPT, should fix the partition table errors. The commands give below will do this. (I assume the external drive is still `disk1`).

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1
sudo dd if=/dev/disk1 of=/dev/disk1 count=32 conv=notrunc seek=2 skip=1953525135
```

> **Even if the above commands fix the partition table errors, there is no guarantee the data, stored in the partitions, has not been corrupted.**